# parse Main Args[] string from windows context menu

Tags: c#, parsing, contextmenu, args

I used the following code to implement the right clicked file that opened by my application.
My aim is to get that file's path into my program.

I use:

```
public static string path = "";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length > 0)
  {
     path = args[0];      
  }
}
```

Then I use the variable `path`, which is the file that opened by the application through the context menu.

#### Problem:

When the file name doesn't contain any spaces, the file path is imported without any problems.
But when the file name contains any spaces, the file name shown without its extension besides it removes letters after the first space in the file name.

#### Example:

1. `fileName.pdf` → `fileName.pdf`
2. `fileName blah blah.pdf` → `filename`

The second example shown that the file that contains spaces didn't imported as it should.

So, if there is any idea of how to parse the files that contains spaces without any problems with its name.

Comment: Then the context menu in explorer would be wrong, the %1 needs to be in quote marks.

Comment: its is quoted :   
string.Format("\"{0}\" \" %1\"", Application.ExecutablePath)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the operating system tries to split out the command line arguments for you, however can get it wrong if you don't put quotes in the right places.  By default the following command line

```
MyConsoleApp.exe FileName blah blah.pdf
```

Will result in `args` containing the 3 strings `FileName`, `blah` and `blah.pdf` (split up by the spaces)

The most common solution to this problem is to surround the argument with quotes when invoking your application, for example

```
MyConsoleApp.exe "FileName blah blah.pdf"
```

This will result in `args` having length 1 with the first string having the value `FileName blah blah.pdf` (the OS strips out the extra quotes).

The alternative is to use the [Environment.CommandLine property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) to obtain the full unparsed command line used to invoke your application, and to manually parse that string.  This gives you more flexibility (as its not always possible to identify whether or not an argument was surrounded by quotes when using the `args` argument passed into Main), however is more effort - you should probably just make sure you use quotes when launching your application.

Comment: it is a nice answer but i cannot put quote the Args cause i comse from context menu without the lost letters

Comment: @HassanWasef How come?  In that case you are probably going to need to parse the `Environment.CommandLine` property

Comment: i think i found a simple way to fix it, it is by converting the "%1" to "%0" i don't know the difference but it worked well .
Thanks alot anyway

Comment: I am trying to pass in file paths to the args array, enclosed in quotes, but the strings are still being parsed wrong. Any idea what this could be? i.e could the backslashes in the path be interfering with it?

Answer (score 0):

Some one posted a perfect answer, but he deleted it before i could upvote it and make it the right answer.

the answer was that i have to change the "%1" to "%0" and it worked.